# Get module name in Zend Framework , bootstrap.php

Tags: zend-framework

I have route in bootstrap.php witch contains :

```
protected function _initRoutes()

{
        $router->addRoute(
            'default',
            new Zend_Controller_router_Route('/:lang/:module/:controller/:action/*',
                array('lang'=>'fa',
                        'module' => ':module',
                        'controller'=>'index',
                        'action'=>'index',
                    )
                )
        );
}
```

But instead of replacing module name , it returns %3module witch is url encoding of :module when i use this line :

```
$this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'index'),'default',true) ;
```

What should i do to get module name from requested URL witch is not working in _initRoutes() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
$router->addRoute(
            'default',
            new Zend_Controller_router_Route('/:lang/:module/:controller/:action/*',
                array('lang'=>'fa',
                        'module' => 'default', //set the default module
                        'controller'=>'index',
                        'action'=>'index',
                    )
                )
        );
```

FYI: [Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard)

Or

Otherwise pass module name into url helper,

```
$module = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
$this->url(array('module'=>$module,'controller'=>'index','action'=>'index'),'default',true) ;
```

Comment: yes , it is what my code look likes at first but i want to get it from url .the problem is, the _initRoutes function can't get url parameters to replace it,i think.